# Could not cast value of type 'Pong.MenuVC' (0x1072ea808) to 'Pong.GameViewController'

Tags: swift, xcode

I have built an app using Xcode and swift 5.

Every time I click the "Easy", "Medium", "Hard" or "2 Player" button I get an error:

> Could not cast value of type 'Pong.MenuVC' (0x1072ea808) to
>   'Pong.GameViewController'

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thank you for your help.

**Code of MenuVC:**

````swift
enum gameType {
    case easy
    case medium
    case hard
    case player2
}

class MenuVC : UIViewController {

    @IBAction func Player2(_ sender: Any) {
        moveToGame(game: .player2)
    }

    @IBAction func Easy(_ sender: Any) {
        moveToGame(game: .easy)
    }

    @IBAction func Medium(_ sender: Any) {
        moveToGame(game: .medium)
    }

    @IBAction func Hard(_ sender: Any) {
        moveToGame(game: .hard)
    }
    ```

    **Code with Thread 1: signal SIGABRT:**

    ```swift
    func moveToGame(game : gameType) {
        let gameVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "gameVC") as! GameViewController

        currentGameType = game

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(gameVC, animated: true)
    }
}
````

**Code of GameViewController:**

```swift
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

var currentGameType = gameType.medium

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                scene.size = view.bounds.size

                // Present the scene
                view.presentScene(scene)
            }

            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
        }
    }

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            return .allButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .all
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your storyboard the id **gameVC** is of type `MenuVC` not `GameViewController` so change class name of the vc

```
let gameVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "gameVC") as! GameViewController
```